# BLE: What could cause BLE connection establishment to fail

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to implement a Bluetooth Low Energy Host on a system with SAM E54 with FreeRTOS. The bluetooth stack I am using is Nimble (Mynewt-NimBLE from Apache). I am trying to connect the SAM E54 to a nRF52840 Dongle (driven with nRF Connect Desktop application).

When I set my device as Central (as a 4.x device, with no 5.x capabilities), the device can connect to another device without error.

But when I switch on the 5.x capabilities, (basically by changing a define's value and calling another API function), and try to connect to the same peripheral, it fails 9 out of 10 times, triggering a "connection supervisor timeout" on both the server and the client.
I tried changing the supervisor timeout value, but it won't fix the problems. When a connection is bound to be successful, the central's information is displayed immediately on nRF Connect. When connection establishment is going to fail, I know it right away (before the connection supervisor timeout is triggered) because no information about the central is displayed on nRF Connect.

Once the connection is established, it can stay on for hours, so I don't think this is an RF noise issue.

I know NimBLE is not initially designed for SAM E54 and FreeRTOS, and surely the problem comes from a wrong implementation or configuration of the stack. But right now I feel like I've tested everything, and I don't know where to dig for solutions.

The actual questions are :

- To start a connection using 4.x BLE capabilities, some HCI commands packets are sent. Should these packets be any different than the packets sent when I enable the 5.x capabilities ? In both cases, I am connecting to a 4.x device.
- What step of the connection establishment process fails when both server & client "think' they are connected, yet don't exchange information?

Comment: Maybe a bad scheduling algorithm or implementation in nimble causes it to miss the BLE events?

Comment: Thank you for the response.
If I read correctly the "initialting a correction" and "initiating a correction that fails to establish" in the Blutooth Core book (V5.1, Vol 6, Part D, 5.1 & 5.5), after a connection was established, there is no required exchange between the host and the controller, so I don't think the host missed some HCI event (if that's what you suggest).

Could you explain about your first idea "bad sheduling algorithm" ? We might be on something, but I don't understant the idea yet.

Comment: I'm talking about the controller side, not host side. So by BLE events I mean link layer connection events. A BLE controller usually only has one radio, so if you have multiple connections, advertisers or scanners going on, you must schedule them some radio time each, so they don't overlap. Any scheduler algorithm sometimes need to miss some event, in case it's not possible to handle all events in the given radio time. But a bad one could miss more events than an optimal one.

Comment: Oh I see, I understant now. The problem now it that the controller run on an other chip, which I don't have access to. And when the central device connects, there is no other service running (adv, scan, other connection...).  Still, I guess if I don't give the controller the right parameters, it won't work anyway. I will double-ckeck the connection parameters related to timings. Thank you for your input